PyTorch LSTM regression: Take only last output value or take all output values of LSTM?
I try to train my first LSTM regression model based on global average temperature data. The temperature is available for every month since January 1st, 1850.
From what I've learned online, I feed 12 months in a row into the LSTM and letting it predict the next month and I do this for all my sequences generated from the data (all data except the last 30 years).
I first only took the last output value from the LSTM and advanced it into the final linear linear layer but I noticed that it is not converging very well. Then I advanced all of the output data of the LSTM (so for every month I get the hidden size: 12 x hidden_size) and it works much better.
So with the second solution I can't put in variable length sequences but I won't do this anyway - right?
What would be the best approach here?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

class LSTMDataset( Dataset ):
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len( self.y )

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample, label = self.x[ idx ], self.y[ idx ]
        return sample.reshape( ( -1, 1 ) ), label.reshape( ( 1 ) )

class LSTMNet( nn.Module ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = 24
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM( input_size=1, hidden_size=self.hidden_size, num_layers=1, batch_first=True )
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear( self.hidden_size * 12, self.hidden_size * 12 ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear( self.hidden_size * 12, 1 ) # 12 is the fixed sequence length (12 months of temperature data)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x, _ = self.lstm( x ) # or x[ :, -1, : ] - which one is preferred?
        x = self.net( x )
        return x

df = pd.read_csv( "globalTemperatures.csv" )
df = df[ [ "dt", "LandAverageTemperature" ] ]
df[ "dt" ] = pd.to_datetime( df[ "dt" ], format="%Y-%m-%d" )

forecastMonths = 12 * 30 # forecast 30 years

sequenceLength = 12 # 12 months are fed into LSTM one after another

trainX = []
trainY = []
testX = []
testY = []
for i in range( len( df ) - sequenceLength ):
    x = np.array( df[ "LandAverageTemperature" ].iloc[ i : i + sequenceLength ] ).astype( np.float32 )
    y = np.array( df[ "LandAverageTemperature" ].iloc[ i + sequenceLength ] ).astype( np.float32 )

    if i + sequenceLength >= ( len( df ) - forecastMonths ):
        testX.append( x )
        testY.append( y )
    else:
        trainX.append( x )
        trainY.append( y )

trainingSet = LSTMDataset( trainX, trainY )
testSet = LSTMDataset( testX, testY )

training_loader = DataLoader( trainingSet, batch_size=1, shuffle=True )
test_loader = DataLoader( testSet, batch_size=1, shuffle=False )

model = LSTMNet()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam( model.parameters(), lr=0.01 )
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

accuracies = []
epochs = 2
for epoch in range( epochs ):
    losses = []
    for i, data in enumerate( training_loader ):
        inputs, labels = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)

        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        losses.append( loss.item() )

    print( f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{epochs}] Loss: {np.mean( losses ):.2f}" )


predictedTemperatures = []
model.eval()
for i, data in enumerate( test_loader ):
    inputs, labels = data

    output = model( inputs )
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
    losses.append( loss.item() )

    predictedTemperatures.append( output.item() )

print( f"Test Loss: {np.mean( losses ):.2f}" )

plt.figure( figsize=(18, 2) )
plt.plot( df[ "dt" ], df[ "LandAverageTemperature" ], label="True Temperatures" )
plt.plot( df[ "dt" ].iloc[ -forecastMonths : ], predictedTemperatures, label="Predicted Temperatures" )
plt.savefig( "temperatures.png" )


You can still input windows of any length. Assume that a batch has the following shape batch_size x timesteps x features.  Then the output of the LSTM is batch_size x timesteps x hidden_size. The linear layer will be applied to all timesteps, it can be 1 or any other number. It does not matter.

But the linear layer has to know the timesteps (in this case 12)? Otherwise the number of neurons won't match the output of the LSTM - right? Also - why do internet tutorials take only x[ :, -1, :] when taking the whole x converges so much better?

Typically you would pool the outputs over the timesteps. You could also look into including the hidden/cell states in what you send to the prediction head. You should also consider next-month prediction - this would be a more typical setup for this sort of problem. Instead of using 12 months to predict the 13th month, you have an arbitrary number of timesteps and each step predicts the next step

@Karl I was also thinking about that, it would be nice to be able to put in arbitrary sequences to predict the next month but I don't know exactly how to implement that. How could I pool the output of the LSTM such that the succeeding linear layer doesn't have to know the initial sequence length?

For predicting next month, your outputs are just your inputs shifted by one. If your full sequence x_full is size (bs, sl), you have x = x_full[:, :-1] and y = x_full[:, 1:]. When doing next month prediction, you wouldn't do any pooling. Each timestep output would go through a linear layer so you have one output per input timestep.
